# Compute inverse of $ABA^{T}$ by its component pseudo-inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, pseudoinverse

Is there a way to compute $(ABA^{T})^{-1}$, for $A \in R^{m,n}, B \in R^{n,n}$ and $m<n$. $B$ is PD, and each row of $A$ contain only one $1$ element, rest are zeros, rows are distinct.

I tried $(A^{T})^{\dagger}B^{-1}A^{\dagger}$, but it is not true, guess it's not correct for Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. $A$ has above structure, so $A^{\dagger} = A^{T}$.

The reason for the question is if I can compute inverse of $B$ only one time, then I can get some speedup to compute $(ABA^{T})^{-1}$ with different $A$, because $\text{pinv}(A)$ is just its tranpose.

Comment: So in other words, $ABA^T$ is a submatrix of $B$. As far as I know there no nice way to compute the inverse of a submatrix using the overall inverse

Comment: yes it's true $ABA^{T}$ is a submatrix of B. the fact that i have to compute sub-matrices inverse thousands of times lead me to this question

Comment: You could try using Sherman Morrison as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1248220/81360)

Comment: thanks. I'll take a look :)

Comment: There are some more ideas [on this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/297567/34894)