# Inverse of rank two update of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, inverse, matrix-equations

I want to calculate the inverse of a real and symmetric matrix when I remove the first row and the first column from it using the [Woodbury formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) (as is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1250091/91407)). However, in my case, while $A−UV$ is invertible, $−I+VA^{−1}U$ is not. Is there another way to compute the inverse of the updated matrix?

More explanation:

I quote a part of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1250091/91407) here:

> $$ A = \begin{bmatrix} a & v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ u_1 & & & \\
>                      u_2 &  &  B &  \\ u_3 & & & \end{bmatrix} $$
> we can take $U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & u_1 \\ 0 & u_2 \\ 0 & u_3 \end{bmatrix}$ and $V = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ 1&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$, so that:
> $$ UV = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ u_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>                      u_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ u_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
> Then $A - UV = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix}$ and provided $a \neq 0$ the update can be done by inverting $(I - VA^{-1}U)$, a $2\times 2$ matrix.

In my example, $a$ can be zero, and matrix $A$ is  symmetric, thus $v_i = u_i$. Also the upper left element of $A^{-1}$ is zero. I define $U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & u_1 \\ 0 & u_2 \\ 0 & u_3 \end{bmatrix}$ and $V = \begin{bmatrix} b & u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\ 1&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$, $b\neq 0$. So:

$$ A - UV = \begin{bmatrix} a-b & 0 & 0& 0\\ 0& & & \\
                     0&  &  B &  \\ 0& & & \end{bmatrix} $$  and thus:

$$ (A - UV)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} (a-b)^{-1} & 0 & 0& 0\\ 0& & & \\
                     0&  &  B^{-1} &  \\ 0& & & \end{bmatrix} $$

and
$$\left(A-UV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(-I+VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}$$
but regardless of the value of $b$, the $2\times 2$ matrix $I - VA^{-1}U$ is always not invertible. Is there a trick or another way to solve this problem?

Comment: You may find it worthwhile to examine the Wikipedia page on the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), specifically the computation of $M^{-1}$ in the Background section.

Comment: Does your matrix $A$ have any known properties, such as being real symmetric, etc.?

Comment: @hardmath Yes. I will add it to the question.

Comment: @Semiclassical I examined the Wikipedia page on the Schur complement following your suggestion but I could figure out a solution.

Comment: @Mah Note that by the [WA-identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity), we have 
$$
\det(A - UV) = \det(A) \det(I - A^{-1}UV) = \det(A) \det(I - VA^{-1}U).
$$
It therefore cannot be true that $A - UV$ is invertible but $-I + VA^{-1}U$ is not.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, you are right. I have made a mistake in another part of the solution that caused this problem. Thank you!