# $M = A N A^t,$ where $A$ not necessarily square, $M, N$ symmetric. If I know $N^{-1}$ exists, is there any easy way to compute $M^{-1}?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have $M = A N A^t,$ where $A$ is not necessarily square, and $M, N$ are symmetric. If I know the inverse of $N,$ is there any particularly easy way to compute the inverse of $M?$ (and yes, I know that $M$ might not be invertible - "compute the inverse" means also "tell me if there is not one").

For background: I am using Newton's method to minimize a function $f$ which can be written as $f = g \circ h,$ with $h$ linear. I can compute and invert the Hessian of $g$ by hand. $A$ is the Jacobian of $h.$

Comment: The given hypothesis are even not sufficient to ensure that the inverse of $M$ exists...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That is part of the question. It is amazing how many people are itching to down-vote a perfectly reasonable question. This forum has certainly gone way downhill.

Comment: Have you tried using the pseudo-inverse?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I am not sure how that would help. See the edit to see where the question came from.

Comment: There's a nice trick using $N^{1/2}$ and SVD in the case that $N$ is positive definite, which is guaranteed in the case that $g$ is strictly convex. I'm not sure if that's of any help in your situation.

Comment: @BenGrossmann $N$ is positive definite in my case, so I am curious to see the trick! In my case, actually $N$ is a rank one perturbation of a diagonal matrix, so the Sherman-Morrison formula (which is mentioned in the thing your answer links to) works, but your mystery trick might work better yet!

Comment: @IgorRivin I don't think the trick is quite as spectacular as I initially thought, but I'll add it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to approach the problem.

I assume that $A$ is of size $m \times n$ with $m < n$. If $A$ has rank less than $m$, then $M$ cannot be invertible. Otherwise, there exists a matrix $B$ such that the matrix $\binom AB$ is invertible. We note that
$$
\pmatrix{A\\B}N\pmatrix{A\\B}^T = \pmatrix{ANA^T & ANB^T\\B^TNA & B^TNB}.
$$
We have
$$
\left[\pmatrix{A\\B}N\pmatrix{A\\B}^T\right]^{-1} = \pmatrix{A\\B}^{-T}N^{-1}\pmatrix{A\\B}^{-1},
$$
which means that it suffices to use the inverse of this large matrix to find the inverse of its submatrix.  As is [discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1248220/81360), this can be done with the help of the Woodbury formula.

---

In the case that $N$ is positive definite, we can write
$$
M = AN^{1/2}[N^{1/2}]^TA^T = (AN^{1/2})(AN^{1/2})^T.
$$
From there, if $AN^{1/2} = U \Sigma V^T$ is an SVD, then we can write
$$
M^{-1} = [U \Sigma \Sigma^T U^T]^{-1} = U [\Sigma \Sigma^T]^{-1} U^T.
$$
Of course, $[\Sigma \Sigma^T]^{-1}$ is the inverse of a square diagonal matrix.

In fact, it is not important to have $N^{1/2}$ be the positive definite square root of $N$ here, it suffices to replace $N^{1/2}$ with $L$ from the Cholesky decomposition $LL^T = N$. Because $N$ is a rank-one update of a diagonal matrix, its Cholesky decomposition is [relatively inexpensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Rank-one_update) to compute