# Solving $(V X V^H)^{-1}$ where $V V^H=I$ and non-square.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

I am looking for a way for calculating

$$ (VXV^H)^{-1}$$
where $X$ is an $N$-by-$N$ diagonal matrix and $V$ is $M$-by-$N$ matrix an (pseudo) orthonormal matrix satisfying $VV^H = I_M$. Here, $I_M$ denotes the identity matrix $M$-by-$M$ and $M<N$. Secondly $(.)^H$ denotes the conjugate transpose (Hermitian) of a matrix.

My question is if I can represent the above expression in a more compact fashion. The problem for me is that $V$ is non-square. If $M=N$, I could have written the above expression in the following form:
$$ (VXV^H)^{-1} = V X^{-1} V^H$$
Which is very easy to compute since $X$ is a diagonal matrix.

Let me clarify my problem a little bit more. I have a program that calculates $$ (VXV^H)^{-1}$$ for each iteration and $X$ changes for each iteration but $V$ is constant. Therefore, I can store the value of $V^{-1}$ for further calculations if needed. Can you help me for simplifying it?
If you don't have any possible way, do you know any iterative algorithm for me to calculate the approximate of it? The matrices will be quite large :)

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the value of $V^{-1}$"; $V$ isn't square, so it has no inverse

Comment: Yes, but instead, can I use something like a pseudo inverse since the result is an MxM matrix?

Comment: With same kind of approach that I outline in the beginning of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4463492/81360), we can get away with only computing the inverse of a $2k \times 2k$ matrix, where $k = M - N$.

Comment: In your case, the pseudoinverse is simply $V^+ = V^H$. I don't see a way to use the pseudoinverse here, though

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be a matrix generated such that
$$
Q = \pmatrix{V\\ W}
$$
is square with orthonormal rows, so that $QQ^H = Q^HQ = I_N$. Note that
$$
QXQ^H = \pmatrix{
VXV^H & VXW^H\\
WXV^H & WXW^H}, \\
QX^{-1}Q^H = \left[QXQ^H\right]^{-1} = \pmatrix{
VXV^H & VXW^H\\
WXV^H & WXW^H}^{-1}.
$$
From there, the inverse that we're after is the top left block of
$$
\pmatrix{VXV^H &0\\0 & WXW^H}^{-1} = \pmatrix{(VXV^H)^{-1} &0\\0 & (WXW^H)^{-1}}.
$$
To obtain this inverse, we can use the [Woodbury formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), noting that
$$
\pmatrix{VXV^H &0\\0 & WXW^H} = \pmatrix{
VXV^H & VXW^H\\
WXV^H & WXW^H} - \pmatrix{
0 & VXW^H\\
WXV^H & 0}\\
= QXQ^H -  \pmatrix{VXW^H\\0}\pmatrix{0 & I_{N-M}} -  \pmatrix{0\\I_{N-M}}\pmatrix{ WXV^H&0}
\\ = 
\underbrace{QXQ^H}_A - \underbrace{\pmatrix{VXW^H & 0\\0 & I_{N-M}}}_{B}\underbrace{\pmatrix{0 & I_{N-M}\\ WXV^H & 0}}_{C}.
$$
With the Woodbury formula, we find that
$$
[A - BC]^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}B(I_{2(N-M)} + CA^{-1}B)CA^{-1}.
$$
where we have $A^{-1} = (QXQ^H)^{-1} = QX^{-1}Q^H$. Notably, $CA^{-1}B$ simplifies to the following $2k \times 2k$ matrix, where $k = N-M$.
$$
CA^{-1}B = \\
\pmatrix{0 & I_{N-M}\\ WXV^H & 0}\pmatrix{V\\W}X^{-1}\pmatrix{V^H & W^H}\pmatrix{VXW^H & 0\\0 & I_{N-M}} =\\
\pmatrix{W\\WXV^HV}X^{-1}\pmatrix{V^HVXW^H & W^H} = \\
\pmatrix{WX^{-1}V^HVXW^H & WX^{-1}W^H\\
WXV^HVX^{-1}V^HVXW^H & WXV^HVX^{-1}W^H}.
$$

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your effort. In the last equation, is the matrix at the lefthand side of the equation inverse, or am I missing something? Thank you again. The solution is very instructive.

Comment: No, it's not the equation for the inverse. It is an expression of the form $(A - UCV)$ (with $C = I$), which allows you to apply the Woodbury formula

Comment: Okay, got it :) I will try to obtain the explicit form of $(VXV^H)^{-1}$. I hope that I can derive on my own :)

Comment: Hello again. I am looking for the solution above for a while. But I could not understand the steps above. Can you explain it a little bit more explicitly?

Comment: If you explain exactly what it is that you don't understand, I'll be happy to clarify

Comment: Hello, I didnt get how we obtained $ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
V X V^H & 0 \\0 & W X W^H \end{array}\right)^{-1}$ from $QX^{-1}Q^H$.

Secondly, in the last equation, $\left(\begin{array}{ll}
V X W^H & I_{M-N}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
I_{M-N} \\
W X V^H
\end{array}\right)$ includes the product of $VXW^H I_{N-M}$ product but the dimensions are mismatches as far as I see.

Comment: @Okan Regarding the second part, I made a mistake; see my latest edit

Comment: @Okan To the first question, we didn't "obtain [the matrix] from $QX^{-1}Q^H$". I'm saying that **if** we have this inverse, then we would be able to extract our answer. After that, I explain how the matrix can be obtained from the other

Comment: Hello again, I got your point now. Only one question: In the  last equation, It seems that  $ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
V X V^H & V X W^H \\
W X V^H & W X W^H
\end{array}\right) =QX^{-1}Q^H$ which is defined as $QXQ^H$ above. Am I mistaken?

Comment: No, I say that $\left(\begin{array}{cc} V X V^H & V X W^H \\ W X V^H & W X W^H \end{array}\right)^{\color{red}{-1}} =QX^{-1}Q^H$, since $QX^{-1}Q^H = (QXQ^H)^{-1}$

Comment: So how the list of the last equality holds? It seems that  $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
V X V^H & V X W^H \\
W X V^H & W X W^H
\end{array}\right)$ is replaced with $QX^{-1}Q^H$, not $QXQ^{H}$. I think I am missing a point and could not got it yet.

Comment: @Okan I was in a hurry when I put the answer down earlier, I see now that I have a lot of confusing errors... I'm working on trying to make everything correct now

Comment: @Okan I think that everything is finally correct, and I have a formula for the inverse now

Comment: Thank you for effort again, it was very helpful. Tomorrow, I derive step by step again and inform you. Right now I really have limited internet connection and just electricity went off couple minutes ago. Than you again for helping at that late hours!